# How to populate star schema database with data from CSV file using jasperETL?

Tags: etl, ssis, star-schema, talend

I'm new to jasperETL and i have to populate star schema database with data from CSV file.
Does anyone know how to perform this task? Maybe there is some tutorial or book, where i can find this information. I searched in the internet but found nothing about this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JaspersoftETL is an OEM of Talend. You can find [tutorials](http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/menu.php) on the talendforge.org website. Specifically, the tutorial "How to design a Job using Repository Metadata" covers loading data from a .csv file into a table. It should be precisely what you need.